# Can I zoom the map with “z” and “a” in Openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers

How can I zoom the map in Openlayers3 with "z" and "a" ? currently I use this function: `map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom()+1)`.
 But I do not know how I can make it work when I press "A" or "Z". 
Another problem is that when i zoom with this function the zoom not follow the mause

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to override default `handleEvent` method which supports only `+` and `-`:

```
var handleEvent = function(mapBrowserEvent) {
  var stopEvent = false;
  if (mapBrowserEvent.type == ol.events.EventType.KEYDOWN ||
    mapBrowserEvent.type == ol.events.EventType.KEYPRESS) {
    var keyEvent = mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent;
    var charCode = keyEvent.charCode;
    if (this.condition_(mapBrowserEvent) && (charCode == 'a'.charCodeAt(0) || charCode == 'z'.charCodeAt(0))) {
      var map = mapBrowserEvent.map;
      var delta = (charCode == 'a'.charCodeAt(0)) ? this.delta_ : -this.delta_;
      var view = map.getView();
      ol.interaction.Interaction.zoomByDelta(map, view, delta, undefined, this.duration_);
      mapBrowserEvent.preventDefault();
      stopEvent = true;
    }
  }
  return !stopEvent;
}

var map = new ol.Map({ ... });

map.getInteractions().forEach(function(interaction) {
    if (interaction instanceof ol.interaction.KeyboardZoom) {
        interaction.handleEvent = handleEvent;
    }
});
```